# Calling a JS script from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following poorly-formed JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript", id="changeTabScript">

    function changeTab(type) {

        String.prototype.contains = function(str) {return this.indexOf(str) != -1;};
        var lbl = document.getElementById('searchLabel').Value;
        if (lbl.contains("Officer"))
        {
            type = "Officer";
        }

        if (type == "Officer")

            $('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#tabs1-officer');

        else

            $('#tab-container').easytabs('select', '#tabs1-company');
    };
</script>
```

I have implemented `Page.RegisterStartupScript("changeTab", "<script language=JavaScript>changeTab </script");`,
however I haven't a clue how `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is formed`. The "key" is something I am unfamiliar with, how do I use the newer implementation?

Comment: The issue is in your Javascript block, function calls should have parenthesis: `changeTab()`. Besides that check MSDN for .NET reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Luizgrs So I can't specify the parameter inside the parenthesis? How do I specify the parameter then?

Comment: yes, you can, but your example was completely missing them, you can do that as usual: `changeTab(1)`. Note I'm talking about the js code block you are inserting through C# not the function definition.

Comment: @Luizgrs if you're saying that `Page.RegisterStartupScript("changeTab", "<script language=JavaScript>changeTab() </script");` should work, it does not.